# Chrome is not launching from pycharm/selenium and gives message Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pycharm, python-unittest

```
import datetime
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


class EnvSetup(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        #self.driver = webdriver.chrome(r"C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Python Download/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver = webdriver.firefox(executable_path="C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Python Download/geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64/geckodriver.exe")
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        #self.driver.i
        print("Browser Started at :" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print("Chrome has been setUP....")
        print("************************************")
        self.driver.close()


    def test_checkBrowser(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/")

    def closeBrowser(self):
        driver = self.driver
        self.driver.save_screenshot('1.png')
        print('Test Completed: Closing the browser...')
        self.driver.close()

    if __name__ ==' main ':
        unittest.main
```

Comment: it is always good to formulate a question in its body

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a cretain things while using *Python's* **unittest** module as follows:

- The constructor is **`webdriver.Firefox()`** but not `webdriver.firefox()`.
- When using *Python's* **unittest** module the method is **`setUp`** but not `setup()`
- If you invoke **`self.driver.close()`** within **`setUp()`** method *Browser* will get closed and no further `Tests` would be executed. So remove the line:

  ```
  self.driver.close()
  ```
- When using *Python's* **unittest** module along with **`setup()`** method you need to use **`tearDown()`** method at the end. So you need to change the method name from `closeBrowser()` to **`tearDown()`**
- If you are assigning `driver = self.driver` then you can invoke the methods directly as:

  ```
  driver.save_screenshot('1.png')
  ```
- Always invoke **`driver.quit()`** within **`tearDown(){}`** method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- Ensure the indents of your code which was incorrect for `__name__ ==' main '`.
- Here is your own program incorporating the above mentioned changes:
- Code Block:

  ```
  import datetime
  import unittest
  from selenium import webdriver

  class EnvSetup(unittest.TestCase):

      def setUp(self):
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
          print("Browser Started at :" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
          print("Chrome has been setUP....")
          print("************************************")

      def test_checkBrowser(self):
          driver = self.driver
          driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/")
          driver.save_screenshot('./Screenshots/1.png')
          print('Test Completed: Closing the browser...')

      def tearDown(self):
          self.driver.quit()

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Finding files... done.
  Importing test modules ... done.

  Browser Started at :2018-09-24 15:07:49.786924
  Chrome has been setUP....
  ************************************
  Test Completed: Closing the browser...
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ran 1 test in 10.911s

  OK
  ```